# Cocoa Window Not Showing on macOS Sierra

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I have the following code to show a new window in my macOS app. This is within a `completionHandler` of a `NSOpenPanel`.

```
let mainStoryBoard = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil)
let windowController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "WindowController")) as! NSWindowController
let myController = windowController.window!.contentViewController as! ViewController
myController.imageView.image = mainImage
windowController.showWindow(self)
```

`mainImage` is defined above that.

Problem is this code works perfectly on macOS High Sierra, but on macOS Sierra the window sometimes displays for a split second then disappears.

Why would this work on macOS High Sierra but not macOS Sierra?

Comment: Maybe one of these objects is released unexpectedly. It's hard to tell without knowing what is their scope and how your app is architectured. But sure I noticed some undocumented changes between 10.11 and 10.12, so maybe there's also undocumented changes between 10.12 and 10.13...

Comment: @Moritz How would I even begin to debug that? Basically on `applicationDidFinishLoading` I have a `NSOpenPanel`, and on the completion handler that code above is being run.

Comment: Maybe have your window conform to NSWindowDelegate then see what happens in `windowWillClose` in Sierra. But it's hard to tell without actually looking at your architecture and the scope of these objects. And I don't know much about NSStoryboard, I'm used to create windows manually with NSWindow so my hint here maybe is not applicable, sorry.

Comment: @Moritz Yeah that function isn't being called.

Comment: Then I'd say one of your objects is indeed released, otherwise windowWillClose would be called. I don't know how to help you debug this further, though. I hope you find the solution.

Comment: "I have the following code"  They never mention where.

Comment: @ElTomato Didn't think it was important in this case haha, will edit my question to add detail that I provided in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this by fixing the scope of `windowController`. Moving that declaration of the variable above the completion handler and setting it to `nil` to start fixed the issue.

I also added the `NSWindowDelegate` and used the function `windowWillClose` to set `windowController` back to `nil` to ensure it is released properly.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck Deferred option of NSWindow.